# changing cyanogenmod dialer behavior: screen goes blank

Tags: cyanogenmod

I updated my Samsung Galaxy S4 with Cyanogenmod 12.  Phone is Sprint SPH-L720 dual band.

When I make or receive a call, when I put the phone to my ear the screen correctly becomes blank.  When I move it away from my face, however, it stays dark.  This thwarts any attempt to hit buttons, such as speaker phone or "press 1" for a menu option.  The screen returns once the call completes.

As I recall, on the stock ROM with the phone, this sort of behavior could be configured with options, but being new to cyanogenmod, I have not found such options.

Regrettably, "cyanogenmod dialer" searches only find things to install new dialers.  So I must rely on your expertise.  Are there options I can change?  Do I just not know the trick to get the screen back?  Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hitting the power button.  If the phone still does not wake up, a second press wakes it up.